# android sqlite - insert syntax error (code 1)

Tags: sqlite, syntax, insert

I cannot figure out what is wrong in my code:

```
    package com.example.lirans88;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "messageDatabase";

    // Messages table name
    private static final String TABLE_MESSAGES = "messages";

    // Messages Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_TEXT = "msg";
    private static final String KEY_FROM = "from";
    private static final String KEY_TO = "to";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_MESSAGES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MESSAGES + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_TEXT + " TEXT," + KEY_FROM + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_TO + " TEXT" + ");";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_MESSAGES_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MESSAGES);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     */

    // Adding new message
    void addMessage(MessageItem message) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ID, 1);
        values.put(KEY_TEXT, "hello");
        values.put(KEY_FROM, "123");
        values.put(KEY_TO, "456");

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_MESSAGES, null, values);            
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }


    // Getting All Messages
    public List<MessageItem> getAllMessages() {
        List<MessageItem> messageList = new ArrayList<MessageItem>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_MESSAGES;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                MessageItem message = new MessageItem();
                message.setId(cursor.getString(0));
                message.setText(cursor.getString(1));
                message.setFrom(cursor.getString(2));
                message.setTo(cursor.getString(3));
                // Adding message to list
                messageList.add(message);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return message list
        return messageList;
    }

    // Getting messages Count
    public int getMessagesCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_MESSAGES;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

}
```

When inserting data into the table using the addMessage function from my app I get these errors:

07-19 11:35:59.129: E/SQLiteLog(1656): (1) near "to": syntax error
07-19 11:35:59.179: E/SQLiteDatabase(1656): Error inserting to=456 id=1 from=123 msg=hello
07-19 11:35:59.179: E/SQLiteDatabase(1656): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "to": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO messages(to,id,from,msg) VALUES (?,?,?,?)

**NOTE:** I temporarily put values in the ContentValues object to rule out a problem with the rest of my app.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`to` and `from` are reserved keywords in SQL.
To use them as identifiers, they should be in `""` double quotes.
Or better yet, just rename the columns.

You should already have gotten a syntax error in your `onCreate()` so apparently it has not been run. Uninstall your app so the old database file is removed and your `onCreate()` with appropriate column names is invoked.